# How can one compute the PRESS diagnostic?

Tags: r, regression, model-selection

If an answer is illustrated with `R` code, it would be even more gratefully accepted.

Comment: What is the statistical question?

Comment: @utobi the question is "how to calculate PRESS". In my opinion this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @Tim as far as I understood the question is "how to calculate PRESS using R", which sounds like performing routine operations within a statistical computing platform, hence off-topic.

Comment: @utobi In its current state, this question seems on-topic to me. I don't think the question is demanding only the R code but the details of computation. It is quite common for "how to compute" questions to express a language preference, but answerers are not obliged to respect it. That is, an answer without R code - using pseudo-code or Python or no code altogether - would still be a valid answer to the question as written. I think the line gets crossed when we see a question that asks how to *implement in R*.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your great answer and I sorry about the way me asking this question.New to the neighbourhood, and still learning.

Comment: @AkiyamaYukari no problem. You can check http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to learn what's on-topic on this site. There was some confusion because questions solely on how to use some software are off-topic, while question of statistical manner are on-topic. Btw, if you find my answer helpful you can mark it as "accepted" (the `v` button on the left of the answer) or upvote it (the upper arrow button) so it is clear that you received an answer and are satisfied with it, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/tour to learn more.

Comment: @Tim Much Thanks! I have accepted it but can ont upvote due to my low reputation. Sorry.

Comment: @AkiyamaYukari I know, this was just for your information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For linear regression model, given the hat matrix

$$ H = X (X'X)^{-1} X' $$

and residuals $e_i$, PRESS [can be calculated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32542/press-statistic-for-ridge-regression) as (see also [here](https://www.otexts.org/1580)):

$$ \mathrm{PRESS} = \sum_i \left(  \frac{e_i}{1-h_{ii}}\right)^2$$

This can be [easily translated](https://tomhopper.me/2014/05/16/can-we-do-better-than-r-squared/) to the simple function:

```r
PRESS <- function(linear.model) {
    pr <- residuals(linear.model)/(1 - lm.influence(linear.model)$hat)
    sum(pr^2)
}
```

Comment: May I ask you to please take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476935/the-best-way-to-compute-the-press-statistic and at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476913/what-assumptions-must-be-satisfied-to-use-r2-to-compute-the-f-statistic